# Official documentaton of com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there official documentation of `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer`?
From the unity scripting [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-plugins-java-code-from-c-sharp.html):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class JavaExamples
{
    public static string GetApplicationCacheDirectory()
    {
       using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
        using (AndroidJavaObject javaFile = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getCacheDir"))
        {
            string cacheDirectory = javaFile.Call<string>("getCanonicalPath");
            return cacheDirectory;
        }
    }
}
```

Here we use `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer` class. I'm looking for all properties of the class and the only thing i found is https://github.com/Geri-Borbas/Unity.Labs.Unity_Player_Android/blob/master/com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer.java.

Is there a official docs of the class from Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently we don't have documentation for our java APIs. We have plans
> to provide it in the future, but it will take a while.

Source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityplayer-class-public-methods-and-properies.1381821/#post-8706093